# Valuation of a polynomial in integers

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

I'm reading a number theory book ("Introduction to number theory", L.K.Hua), and there is a statement that I don't understand at pag $479$.

Suppose we have a polynomial with integer coefficients $$g(x,y) = \sum_{r+s \leq n-3}g_{rs} x^r y^s .$$ Suppose that $G = \max(|g_{rs}|)$. Then if $a,b$ are integers with $|a| \leq b$ we have $$|g(a,b)| \leq G(1 + 2b + \cdots + (n-2)b^{n-3}) .$$

Why ?

Comment: e.g. $|g_{02}x^0y^2|+|g_{11}x^1y^1|+|g_{20}x^2y^0|\le Gb^2+Gb^2+Gb^2=3Gb^2$

Comment: @vadim123: I don't understand, how is your argument related with $|g(a,b)| \leq G(1 + 2b + \cdots + (n-2)b^{n-3}) $ ?

Comment: Okay, I'll give you a full answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We group the terms by the sum of the exponents, $t=r+s$.
$$g(x,y)=\sum_{t=0}^{n-3} \sum_{r=0}^t g_{r,t-r}x^ry^{t-r}$$
$$|g(a,b)|\le \sum_{t=0}^{n-3}\sum_{r=0}^t |g_{r,t-r}a^rb^{t-r}|\le$$
$$\le \sum_{t=0}^{n-3}\sum_{r=0}^t G|a^rb^{t-r}|\le$$
$$\le \sum_{t=0}^{n-3}G\sum_{r=0}^t |b^{t}|=$$
$$=\sum_{t=0}^{n-3}G(t+1) |b^{t}|=G(b^0+2b^1+3b^2+\cdots+(n-2)b^{n-3})$$